# Калькулятор не инициализирует read, при его вызове через функцию, как вызвать метод объекта при вызове функции?

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
const createObjectCalculator = (initialA, initialB) => {
  let calculator = {
    read() {
      this.a = initialA;
      this.b = initialB;
    },

    sum() {
      return this.a + this.b;
    },

    mul() {
      return this.a * this.b;
    },
  };
  return calculator;
};


const calculator = createObjectCalculator(2, 3);
console.log(calculator.sum()); // NaN
console.log(calculator.mul()); // NaN
calculator.read(12, 34);
console.log(calculator.sum()); // 5
console.log(calculator.mul()); // 6
```

Comment: Ваш код не делает то, что Вы написали.

Comment: При запуске сниппета вывод не соответствует комментариям.

Comment: поправил код, вот приложил картинку

Answer (score 0):

В данном коде две ошибки:

1. неверное использование начальных значений `initialA`, `initialB` - в приведенном коде, эти значения устанавливаются не при инициализации объекта, а при вызове метода `read`. Вместо этого нужно было сразу записать их в соответствующие поля:

   ```
   const createObjectCalculator = (initialA, initialB) => {
       let calculator = {
           a: initialA,
           b: initialB,
   ```
2. Судя по использованию, метод `read` должен принимать два параметра, однако реализация не принимает ни одного. Для решения достаточно использовать переданные параметры:

   ```
   read(a, b) {
       this.a = a;
       this.b = b;
   },
   ```

Пример:

```js
const createObjectCalculator = (initialA, initialB) => {
  let calculator = {
    a: initialA,
    b: initialB,
    read(a, b) {
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
    },

    sum() {
      return this.a + this.b;
    },

    mul() {
      return this.a * this.b;
    },
  };
  return calculator;
};


const calculator = createObjectCalculator(2, 3);
console.log(calculator.sum()); // 5
console.log(calculator.mul()); // 6
calculator.read(12, 34);
console.log(calculator.sum()); // 46
console.log(calculator.mul()); // 408
```

Comment: спасибо, заработало!!!